# Conjugacy classes of 2-groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $a_n$ be the smallest number of conjugacy classes a group with $2^n$ elements can have.

> Question 1: What is $a_n$? Can one show that $a_n$ is strict monotone increasing?

The sequence starts for $n=0,1,2,...$ with 1,2,4,5,7,11,13,14.

> Question 2: What is $a_{p,n}$ for a fixed prime $p$ more generally, when $a_{p,n}$ is the smallest number of conjugacy classes of a group with $p^n$ elements?

For example for $p=3$ the sequence starts with     1, 3, 9, 11, 17, 19, 41....

Comment: I can never understand questions like "what is $a_n$?". What sort of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @DerekHolt I have no idea of group theory, so I dont know what to expect. But maybe there is even a nice formula? The sequence starts the same as "Numbers n such that n-th and (n+2)th triangular numbers sum up to a prime", see https://oeis.org/A128815. That would be nice, but my computer is too slow to calculate more terms.